# Adding a complex html / css / js element to a single Wordpress page

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I've created a website (blog) using a theme; the website needs a page with a unit converter so I've gone ahead and created one using html, css and vanilla JS on Codepen.
http://codepen.io/jacobbanner/pen/oxeoqp

```
Codepen above ^^^
```

I also have the wordpress page for the converter setup here: 
http://engineeringbible.com/index.php/converter/

I'm having trouble finding a way to get the converter 'onto' the wordpress page. I've tried adding it to the *edit page* text area, and also the 'additional code' section. The html elements are displayed, but the styling is completely wrong.

Do I need to create it as a separate entity like a plugin or a widget and then add it into the page? Or perhaps there's a particular file location on the server a I need to place my separate js and css?

Comment: better to create separate plugin for this , or if you dont want , you can create special template for this page and include the js in it

Comment: Create a shortcode. That way you'll be able to add it to any page

Comment: Either create a plugin or add it to your theme's functions.php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.  I ended up editing the theme's css file and adding my custom classes, adding my js to the theme js file, and pasting html into the 'additional code' tab in the editor on the page.  I had to adjust positioning settings a bit, but It did work.  Not sure this is the most robust solution but it worked for me.

Comment: This way seems the most straightforward for the single use I need it for, thanks! It's working well now despite having to change some styling!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways how to do this. One of the easiest way how to achieve this - just create seperate CSS and JS files with your code and include these files in your themes header.php file.

You can also create seperate theme file for this page ("Custom Page Templates" section):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Answer (score 1):

In your `functions.php` or in separate file that you include add this:

```
//[converter_shortcode]

add_action('init', 'register_my_script');
add_action('wp_footer', 'print_my_script');

function register_my_script() {
    wp_register_script('converter_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/converter.js', array(), '', true );
}

function print_my_script() {
    global $add_my_script;

    if ( ! $add_my_script )
        return;

    wp_print_scripts('converter_script');
}

function converter_function( $atts ){
    global $add_my_script;

    $add_my_script = true;

    return '
    <div class="converter-wrapper">
      <h1>ENGINEERING UNIT CONVERTER</h1>

      <form name="property_form">
        <span>
          <select class="select-property" name="the_menu" size=1 onChange="UpdateUnitMenu(this, document.form_A.unit_menu); UpdateUnitMenu(this, document.form_B.unit_menu)">
          </select>
        </span>
      </form>

      <div class="converter-side-a">
        <form name="form_A" onSubmit="return false">
          <input type="text" class="numbersonly" name="unit_input" maxlength="20" onKeyUp="CalculateUnit(document.form_A, document.form_B)">
          <span>
            <select name="unit_menu" onChange="CalculateUnit(document.form_B, document.form_A)">
            </select>
          </span>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="converter-side-b">
        <form name="form_B" onSubmit="return false">
          <input type="text" class="numbersonly" name="unit_input" maxlength="20" onkeyup="CalculateUnit(document.form_B, document.form_A)">
          <span>
            <select name="unit_menu" onChange="CalculateUnit(document.form_A, document.form_B)">
            </select>
          </span>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>';

}
add_shortcode( 'converter_shortcode', 'converter_function' );
```

Now in your theme `js` folder create `converter.js` file and add your javascript. In your `css` file add your styling, and you're done.

Now I tried it but I got an error

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByClass is not a function

on line 194, so you might want to check that out. But this is the gist of it...